# How to get number in NSString(with both numbers and characters)?

Tags: nsstring, numbers, character

I fetch the data from site into NSString like this:

```
        <td><font color=#ffffff>35</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>1</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>2</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>1</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>16</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>45.2</td>
        <td><font color=#ffffff>3.153</td>
```

and I want to convert into NSArray with numbers only.

I have been tried many classed and methods.. 
floatValue, componentsSeparatedByString, substringWithRange, .. all look like terrible and inefficient.
Is there any basic method to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best general way to solve this is by using regular expressions.  The regular expression

`-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*`

matches an optional negative sign, followed by some digits, followed by an optional decimal point, optionally followed by some more digits.  Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html for a nice discussion on how to best match numbers with a regular expression.  The regex I give here is simpler than any shown on that page, but it's somewhat less robust.

To match regular expressions in Objective-C, you can use an NSRegularExpression.  It has a function called enumerateMatchesInString that will call a code block every time it gets a match within a string.  Here's an example of how you could use that to build up an array of NSNumbers:

```
NSString *str = @"<td><font color=#ffffff>35</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>1</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>2</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>0</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>1</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>16</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>45.2</td>\
<td><font color=#ffffff>3.153</td>";
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray new];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"-?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*" options:NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace error:nil];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    NSString *substr = [str substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:substr];
    if (number) {
        [numbers addObject:number];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"ARRAY: %@", numbers);
```

Comment: COOL! It works perfectly!
Thanks for your help and the link you gave. It really benefits me a lot!